# Questions about Orthogonal vs Perspective in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, matrix, 3d

I've gotten a 3 vertices triangle rotating around the y-axis. One of the things I find "weird" is normalized coordinates in GL's default orthogonal projection. I've used 2-D libraries like SDL and SFML, which almost always deal with pixels. You say you want an image surface that is 50x50 pixels, that is what you get. So initially it was strange for me to say limit my vertex position choices from [-1,1].

**Why do orthogonal coordinates have to be normalized? Is perspective projection the same? If so, how would you say you want the origin of your object to be at z=-10?** (My quick look over matrix m ath says perspective is different. Something about division by 'w' creating homogenous (same thing as normalized?) coordinates, but I'm not sure).

> gl_Position = View * Model * Project * Vertex;

I've seen that equation above and I'm boggled by how the variable gl_Position used in shaders can represent both the position of the current vertices of a model/object, and at the same time a view/projection, or the position of the camera. **How does that work?** I understand by multiplication all that information is stored in one matrix, but how does OpenGL use that one matrix whose information is now combined to say, "ok, this part/fraction of gl_Position is for the camera, and that other part is information for where the model is going to go."? **(BTW, I'm not quite sure what the Vertex vec4 represents. I thought all vertices of a model were inside Model. Any ideas?**

One more question, if you just wanted to move the camera, for example in FPS games you move the mouse up to look up, but no objects are being rotated or translated (I think) other than the camera, would the equation above look something like this?

> gl_Position = View * Project;

Comment: I believe you don't have a slightest idea what a matrix is.

Comment: the only thing openGL "knows" is that it has to draw points that fall inside [-1,-1,1,1] as outpued in glPosition by the vertex shader. All those matrixes operations are there to map your world objects (which can have origin at z=-10) to that square. Vector4  and w is used to ease some calculation during the perspective transformation. You will need a book to understand all details.

Comment: @Bartek: Probably not. My perception of it right now is that [p,q,r] stands for each of the basis vectors or each of them is a linear equation.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why do orthogonal coordinates have to be normalized?

They don't. You can set the limits of the orthogonal projection volume however you desire. The left, right, bottom, top, near and far parameters of the glOrtho call define the limits of the viewport volume. If you chose them left=0, right=win_pixel_width, bottom=0, top=win_pixel_height you end up with a pixel unit projection volume as you're used to. However why bother with pixels? You'd just have to compensate for the actual window size later. Just choose the ortho projection volume extents to match the scene you want to draw.

Maybe you're confusing this with normalized device coordinates. And for those it simply has been defined that it is the value range [-1, 1] that's mapped to the viewport extents.

#### Update

> BTW, I'm not quite sure what the Vertex vec4 represents. I thought all vertices of a model were inside Model. Any ideas?

I'm getting quite fatigued right now, because I've been answering several questions like this numerous times over the last few days. So, here it goes again:

**In OpenGL there is no camera.**

**In OpenGL there is no scene.**

**In OpenGL there are no models.**

"Wait, what?!" you may wonder now. But it's true.

All OpenGL cares about is, that there is some target framebuffer, i.e. a canvas it can draw to, and a stream of vertex attributes that make geometric primitives. The primitives are points, lines and triangles. Somehow the vertex attributes for, say a triangle, must be mapped to a position on the framebuffer canvas. For this an vertex attribute we call *position* goes through a number of affine transformations.

The first is from a local *model* space into world space , the *Model* transform.

From world space into eye space, the *View* transform. It is this view transform, which acts like placing the camera in a scene.

After that it put through the equivalent of a camera's lens, which is a Projection transform.

After the Projection transform the position is in *clip space* where it undergoes some operations, that are not essential to understand for the time being. After clipping the so called homogenous divide is applied to reach normalized device coordinate space, by dividing the clip space position vector by its own w-component.

```
v_position_ndc = v_position_clip / v_position_clip.w
```

This step is, what makes a perspective projection actually work. The z-distance of a vertex' position is worked into the clip space w-component. And by the homogenous divide vertices with a larger position w get scaled proportionally to 1/w in the XY plane which creates a perspective effect.

*You mistook this operation as normalization, but it is not!*

After the homogenous divide vertex position has been mapped from clip to NDC space. And OpenGL defines, that the visible volume of NDC space is the box [-1, 1]^3 ; vertices outside this box are clipped.

It's crucial to understand that View transform and Projection are different. For a position it's not so obvious, but another vertex attribute called the normal, which is an important ingredient for lighting calculations, must be transformed in a slightly different way (instead of `Projection · View · Model` it must be transformed by `inverse(transpose(View · Model))`, i.e. the Projection takes no part in it but the viewpoint does).

The matrices itself are 4×4 grids of real valued scalars (ignore for the time being that numbers in a computer are always rational numbers). So the rank of the matrix is 4 and hence it must be multiplied of vectors of dimension 4 (hence the type *vec4*)

OpenGL treats vertex attributes as column vectors so matrix multiplication is left associative i.e. a vector enters an expression on the right side and comes out on the left. **The order of matrix multiplication matters. You can not freely reorder things!**

The statement

```
gl_Position = Projection * View * Model * vertex_position; // note the order
```

makes the vertex shader perform this very transformation process I just described.

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers: Please see my answer update, as I added significant amount of information relevant for you.

Comment: Thank you datenwolf. I appreciate it and that was helpful. Forgive me for not knowing the basics, but I've never been exposed to linear algebra and its relation to 3-D graphics. I'm doing this as a hobby and I'm not gifted at math so it's all very difficult for me. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

"Note that there is no separate camera (view) matrix in OpenGL. Therefore, in order to simulate transforming the camera or view, the scene (3D objects and lights) must be transformed with the inverse of the view transformation. In other words, OpenGL defines that the camera is always located at (0, 0, 0) and facing to -Z axis in the eye space coordinates, and cannot be transformed. See more details of GL_MODELVIEW matrix in ModelView Matrix."

Source: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html

That is what I was getting hung up on. I thought there would a separate camera view matrix in OpenGL.